# window.onerror / window.addEventListener do not get triggered in my Production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client, dom-events

I tried to add window.onError and window.addEventListener like in my main.tsx file

```
try {
  window.onerror = (message: string, source: string, lineno: number, colno: number, error: Error) => {
    console.log("reached inside the window.onerror");
    console.log(message);
  };
} catch (e) {
  console.log("reached the catch block");
  const message = getErrorMessage(e);
  logErrors(ClickEvent.GLOBAL_ERROR_LOG, message, ErrorEventLog.FATAL, pageId);
}
```

In a similar fashion, I tried window.addEventListener

```
window.addEventListener('error', event => {
 console.log('insideventlistener');
 console.log(event);
});
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
 console.log('unhandledrejection');
 return logClientSideError(event.reason);
});
```

Injected error looks something like this:

```
render() {
  const sample = null;
  return <div>{sample.abc}</div>;
}
```

Problem:

In local/Dev environment - The window.onerror or window.addEventListener gets triggered, and the console.log statements show up in the browser console along with the error.

However, when I push the code to the production environment, they never get triggered. (But the error shows up in the browser console) Am I missing anything?

We have an error boundary also added to parts of our code.

Error in browser console in Prod

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2273 TypeError: Cannot read property 'as' of null
    at t.render (main.js:8)
    at un (main.js:37)
    at sn (main.js:37)
    at Bu (main.js:45)
    at ta (main.js:37)
    at $n (main.js:37)
    at Wn (main.js:37)
    at main.js:37
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (main.js:69)
    at Wt (main.js:37)
    at Qt (main.js:37)
    at Kt (main.js:37)
    at Fn (main.js:37)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (main.js:45)
    at o.a.setState (main.js:61)
    at t (main.js:2)
    at main.js:2
```

Comment: Please add the error stack trace that shows up when the code is deployed in production. It would help in better identification and debugging of the problem.

Comment: @KunalKukreja Done. edited the post with the details. Thanks